# When delete something in page , refresh all values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items. I can create some items. The problem is that when I push the delete button I want all values to refresh and change. How can I do that?

For example when I delete the third number, then the fourth tag will be third.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".addnew", function() {
  id = this.id;
  var idsh = parseInt(id.substr(3));
  var ids = parseInt(id.substr(3)) + 1;
  document.getElementById("ad_" + idsh).style.display = "none";
  kanban = document.getElementById("kanban");
  var btn = document.createElement("p");
  btn.id = "main_" + ids;
  btn.innerHTML =
    '<span type="text" id="co_' + ids + '" class="counter text-center bg-success text-white" >' + ids + ' </span>' +
    '<span  id="mo_' + ids + '" class="formulbitti text-center bg-success text-white" > inner </span>' +
    '<button id="de_' + ids + '" class="delete text-center bg-success text-white" >delete</button> ' +
    '<button type="text" id="ad_' + ids + '" class="addnew text-center bg-success text-white" >add</button>';
  kanban.appendChild(btn);
});

$("body").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  id = this.id;
  var ids = id.substr(3);
  $('#main_' + ids).remove();

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div id="kanban">
  <span type="text" id="co_1" class="counter text-center bg-success text-white">1</span>
  <span type="text" id="mo_1" class="formulbitti text-center bg-success text-white">inner</span>
  <button type="text" id="de_1" class="delete text-center bg-success text-white">delete</button>
  <button type="text" id="ad_1" class="addnew text-center bg-success text-white">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Do not use incremental `id` attributes*. As you can see in your code they add needless complication and have absolutely no benefit.

The best method to do what you require is to use DOM traversal to relate elements to each other. The only tweak you need to make to your HTML is to add a new `div` to group the `span` and `button` elements. From there when a button is clicked you can use `closest()` to retrieve the nearest `.row` container and clone/remove it.

The benefit of this is that the HTML becomes standardised and the JS to work with it is the same, regardless of the content or position.

To solve the issue of the counters being updated when an action is performed, create a function which iterates through all the `.counter` elements and updates their text based on their index in the DOM.

Finally note that `button` elements have a `type` of `button` or `submit`, never `text`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let $kanban = $('#kanban');
let updateCounters = () => $kanban.find('.counter').text(i => i + 1);

$(document).on("click", ".addnew", e => {
  $(e.target).closest('.row').clone().appendTo($kanban);
  updateCounters();
});

$(document).on("click", ".delete", e => {
  $(e.target).closest('.row').remove();
  updateCounters();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div id="kanban">
  <div class="row">
    <span type="text" class="counter text-center bg-success text-white">1</span>
    <span type="text" class="formulbitti text-center bg-success text-white">inner</span>
    <button type="button" class="delete text-center bg-success text-white">delete</button>
    <button type="button" class="addnew text-center bg-success text-white">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

One last thing to note is that it's a litte odd to have a table-level 'add' button on each row. It would make more sense to have a single add button at the top or bottom of the content.

Comment: First of all very thanks for your time to asnwer my question... for the second thing this is a very very very small part of my reall "code"... your asnwer do what to do right. but for me it is needless. for Example I could do someting like "find last element and delete it"...

But I want all of my codes refresh..

For example "ad_3" become "ad_2" after I delete 2th row...

Comment: Exactly my point - don't do that. There is no need to.

Comment: :)) I need that cause I am usimng those id to change something elses...:D

Comment: In that case start a new question about that, as there's much better ways to achieve it.

Comment: maybe I think best soluton is making a while loop and get "id number" from "delete button" and after "that id" find all i"d numbers "and "-1" all of them one by one